# How to call a Haskell State function?

Tags: haskell

I've written a whole lot of exercises now on functions that **use** State, like

```hs
addStateAndReturnResult :: Int -> State Int Int
addStateAndReturnResult x = do
    state <- get
    put $ state + x
    return $ state + x
```

But I have no idea how to actually **call** the function and get the result out. Something like this gives me a weird type error that is not even close:

```hs
callIt :: Int
callIt = addStateAndReturnResult 3 (State 1)
```

How do I make function run please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three functions for this.

The most general is [`runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:runState). It returns a tuple of the last state and the final return value.

Then there is [`evalState :: State s a -> s -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:evalState) which just returns the final return value.

And there is [`execState :: State s a -> s -> s`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:execState) which just returns the last state value.

In your case, you probably want `evalState`:

```
callIt = evalState (addStateAndReturnResult 3) 1
```